# Из-за программа для маршрутизации запросов забивается оперативная память

Tags: маршрутизатор

Здравствуйте.

Bgs Communication Routing Service - программа для маршрутизации запросов. Постоянно забивается оперативная память и когда доходит до критического значения, сервис останавливается. И потом нужно запускать вручную, чтобы он стартовал! Что можно придумать, чтобы память не забивалась постоянно!

Answer (score 1):

копать в сторону параметров запуска....или же там должны быть настройки на эту тему